# Transform Word Document data into showing the "new line" separator within the text

Tags: python, csv, text, ms-word

So I'm trying to get a standard word document into a csv format which includes the "\n" new line indicator or "\n" within the text itself. I'll be using this data so I can fine-tune a natural language model I'm working on.

So for example,

> ```
> Hey there,
>
> My name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I believe my job history fits perfectly within the Microsoft Culture.
>
> Thanks!
> Jim
> ```

Would become

Hey there,**\n** My name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I believe my job history fits perfectly within the Micorosoft Culture. **\n**Thanks! **\n**Jim

I tried using Notepad++ to show the line breaks, which it did, but it was in a weird format and not actually displaying the text but just visually showing where the line breaks were.

Answer (score 1):

Use `repr()` to show the string representation of the string.

e.g.

```
text = """Hey there,

My name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I believe my job history fits perfectly within the Microsoft Culture.

Thanks!
Jim"""

new_text = repr(text)
```

Output:

> ```
> print(new_text)
> > "Hey there,\n\nMy name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I believe my job history fits perfectly within the Microsoft Culture.\n\nThanks!\nJim"
> ```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, didn't know python had this lol